# SQL Server Express 2016 user works in SSMS but not from application via internal IP

Tags: sql-server

I am using Google Compute instances with a SQL Server Express 2016 database on one instance and an application on another instance. The database is set up to work with either SQL Server or Windows authentication.

The application connects to the database using the internal IP address. All is well as long as the SQL Server user is `sa`, but when I change it to another user I set up, it won't connect and gives this error:

> An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

I looked at the application log which gives a longer error but not helpful (at least to me). But as soon as I change the connection string back to `sa`, everything is fine.

I am able to access the database via SSMS with the new login, so I know it's legitimate, at least locally. I've restarted the database server several times. Obviously there's something I'm missing; just don't know what it is.

Point taken: Here is the log:
ERROR [2020-06-29 22:39:35,828] [XXXXXXXXXXXX.Controllers.UserController.Authenticate] Unable to Login with Message- An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
Stack Trace:    at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at XXXXXXXXXXXX.Controllers.UserController.AuthenticateUser(String userName, String password)
at XXXXXXXXXXXX.Controllers.UserController.Authenticate(String userName, String password, String returnUrl)
XXXXXXXXXXXX.Controllers.UserController.Authenticate(System.String userName, System.String password, System.String returnUrl)

You are correct, it is a permissions issue. If I change the user and give it sysadmin permissions, it works great; however I was hoping to dial down the permissions for this SQL login. Is that not possible/advisable?

Thanks,
Sally

Comment: You should post the relevant error message from your log even if you don't understand it. We have very few clues to help you. The only thing I can tell is this could be a permission issue of some sort since user sa can connect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986160/an-error-occurred-while-executing-the-command-definition-see-the-inner-exceptio)

Comment: Thanks Alex but no. I assume if any of those issues were the case, this would not be working with the 'sa' user. It's permissions but I was hoping not to have to give the second SQL user sysadmin permissions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28331551/6305294 - this one deals with permissions.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm working with a self-contained database. There are no Views that rely on another database. I think I'm just going to have to figure out how to alter the database to accept a non-administrative login.